# Twitter followers

Tags: r, twitter

I'm using `R` packages `twitteR` and `rtweet`. There are functions to get the followers of a specified user. Is there any way to know when user A has started following user B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not available in the Twitter API so neither of those libraries can provide that data.